# Как лучше сделать такое меню

Tags: html, css, меню

Собственно вот макет и в планшетно-мобильном меню элементы с шапки должны появляться в блоке меню, как лучше сделать так, потому что я попробовал позиционировать эти элементы абсолютно указав в пикселях свойство bottom, глянул на мобиле, все съехало, думаю это не лучший вариантю
Нормально ли будет в html сверстать эти элементы отдельно в блоке меню и показывать только на маленьких экранах, а старые скрывать? Нормальная ли это практика или костыль?
[[image: макет][1]

```
<header class="header wrapper">
    <div class="topline">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="logo-img" src="image/-e-logo.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="menu" id="menu">
            <ul class="menu-list" >
                <li class="menu-list__item">
                    <a class="menu-list__item-link" href="#">Раздел №1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-list__item">
                    <a class="menu-list__item-link" href="#">Раздел №2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-list__item">
                    <a class="menu-list__item-link" href="#">Раздел №3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-list__item">
                    <a class="menu-list__item-link" href="#">Раздел №4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-list__item">
                    <a class="menu-list__item-link" href="#">Раздел №5</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="compare-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="compare">
                <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i>
                <span class="compare__text">Сравнение</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="lk-wrapper">
            <button class="lk">Личный кабинет</button>
        </div>
        <div class="header__phone">
            <a class="header__phone-link" href="tel:+7 000 000-00-00">+7 000 000-00-00</a>
            <div class="phone-btn">
                <a class="fa fa-phone phone-btn__link" aria-hidden="true" href="tel:+70000000000"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: а если поступить по другому, сворачивать не меню а `header`, это вариант ?

Comment: всмысле topline? потому что в хедере у меня будет еще картинка с тайтлом, типа сделать .topline height: 100vh и там уже позиционировать все?

Comment: наверно так ... не обязательно же само меню сворачивать ..мы то по идее можем свернуть всё что угодно ...

Comment: я не понимаю что ты хочешь сказать)

Comment: я говорю о том что мы можем свернуть любой элемент страницы и так же я не вижу мобильную версию ...особенно то как выглядит `header` и как `menu` именно в мобильной версии

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/g0M6poj_3Wt4H5

Comment: тогда здесь ещё проще чем ожидалось ...логотип за пределами меню а его уже извращать .... так надо за вас сделать ? уроки адаптивной вёрстки здесь не дают

Comment: дак а если просто свертать отдельно мобильное меню и уже его разворачивать, это хрень получится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так адаптируют меню ....

Полностью готово, кроме того что надо скрывать сложенные элементы: вставлять кнопки и подключать js ...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-right: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu,
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.logo,
ul li a,
.user_panel span {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.menu {
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: space-between
}

ul li a,
.user__panel span {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}

.fa {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.lk {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.fa-sort-desc {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: translate(0, -3px);
}

@media (max-width:1300px) {
  ul li a,
  .user__panel span {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  ul li {
    margin: 0 6px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:1044px) {
  ul li a,
  .user__panel span {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:850px) {
  .element {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100px;
  }
  .user__panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .user__panel span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:640px) {
  .element {
    background: #fbfbfb;
    border: none;
  }
  .menu {
    padding-left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
    width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: #fbfbfb;
  }
  .menu ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    align-content: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 3px 0;
  }
  .user__panel {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    border: none;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  .tel {
    float: left;
  }
  .lk {
    border: none;
  }
  .lk .fa {
    display: none;
  }
  .user__panel span {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .user__panel .fa {
    padding: 0 2px;
  }
  .fa-whatsapp {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  ul li a,
  .user__panel span {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie|Courgette|Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="logo">
        company
      </div>

      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Раздел1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Раздел2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Раздел3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Раздел4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Раздел5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="user__panel">
          <span><i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i>Сравнение</span>
          <span class="lk">Личный кабинет <i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <span class="tel">+7 000 000-00-00</span>
          <span><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, возьму на заметку на будущее, я в принципе так и предполгал, что нужно абсолютно позиционировать элементы которые будут скрываться, даже попробовал так сделать, но начались проблемы с jquery, а именно возникала задержка при скрытии элементов и изчезал эффект раскрытия, ничего не смогу с этим поделать и сделал через отдельную верстку блоков вот так https://ldarksoull.github.io/Company/

Comment: @QuadenChannel  я помог вам или нет?

Comment: Советом, да, спасибо